# Html forms enter press

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have made a console using html,css,javascript

the input does not appears on enter press 
the send button should b pressed 
how to make it go on enter press

the code is given here please help

/* code goes below*/

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
   <title>Konsole</title>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0"/>
  </head>
 <body>
 <style>
  body{
    monospace
    }
body{
color:#52cc29;
background-color:black;
font-family:monospace;
}
div.textarea > textarea{
height:80vh;
width:95%;
font-family:monospace;
font-size:20px;
font-weight:bold;
color:#52cc29;
background-color:black;
border:5px solid white;
}
input.command{
height:30px;
width:70%;
background-color:black;
border:3px solid white;
color:#52cc29;
font-size:15px;
text-align:left;
padding-left:4px;
font-family:monospace;
font-weight:bold;
}
h3{
font-family:monospace;
font-size:20px;
font-weight:bold;
}
input.send{
background-color:black;
color:#52cc29;
font-family:monospace;
font-weight:bold;
height:35px;
width:60px;
font-size:20px;
}

 </style>

 <script>

   function chat(){
   
   var time = new Date();
   var hours = time.getHours();
   var min = time.getMinutes();
   var sec = time.getSeconds;
   var write = document.getElementById("area2").value;
   var read = document.getElementById("area1").value;
   
   
   var newRead = "you at " +" "+hours+"h:"+min+"m"+" : " + write + "\n" + read;
   document.getElementById("area1").value = newRead;

switch(write){
case "@echo.off" : document.getElementById("area1").value = "echo is off";
break;

}
   }


 </script>
 <center>

<h3>Console</h3>

<form id="form1" >
      <div class="textarea">
         <textarea autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" 
   autocorrect="off" autocomplete="off" id="area1" readonly ></textarea>
      </div>
   </form>
   <form id="form2">
      <div class="input">
         <input autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" autocorrect="off" autocomplete="off" class="command" id="area2"  placeholder="type command here"></input>
   
         <input  class="send" type="button" id="button" value="send" onclick="chat();">
      </div>
   </form>
</center>

 
   
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script>
    window.addEventListener("keypress",handleKey);

    function handleKey(e){
     if(e.keyCode == 13){
      chat();
     }
    }
</script>
```